# Parsing data from php page to android

Tags: java, php, android, xml, parsing

So I'm learning android and I'm trying to parse the data from the following website:

http://www.brimfieldfleafinder.com/dealersservc.php

I'm not sure what kind of format this is. It seems to be XML but mixed with something else ? I have tried parsing it as XML using both an XMLParser and an org.xml.sax parser but I getting two issues:

1. When I try to download the data as a String from the specified URL using the `getUrlString()` method from the following code and use the logcat or a toast to visualize it, I just get a bunch of question mark characters inside a diamond shape.

   ```
   public byte[] getUrlBytes(String website) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(website);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

     try {
       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

       if (connection.getResponseCode() != connection.HTTP_OK) {
         throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage());
       }

       int bytesRead = 0;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       while ((bytesRead = in.read()) > 0) {
         out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
       out.close();

       return out.toByteArray();
     } finally {
       connection.disconnect();
     }
   }

   public String getUrlString(String website) throws IOException {
     return new String(getUrlBytes(website));
   }
   ```
2. The other issue I have is that when I try to parse the result as an XML I get an error saying its not a valid xml. I suppose those question marks cant be valid XML after all, but I've tried running the above URL through an XML validator and still says its not valid XML.

So again, what kind of data is this and how can I parse it ?

Comment: It's not XML, it's just a list separated by a delimiter

Comment: Thanks, so how can I parse/use the data? if you use the browser inspector you can see the data separated by tags such as <dealer></dealer>

Comment: It's not valid XML, but it does look like it could be used. It seems to be HTML wrapped in HTML. You could try to remove all tags from the string such as <html></html><body></body>. Then add the correct XML tags to the start and end of the remaining string. You may then be able to load this new string into the XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Below is an example to get the data from the page

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ExtractInfo  {

   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{ 

       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.brimfieldfleafinder.com/dealersservc.php").get(); //get the page
       Elements dealersList = doc.select("dealer"); // select all dealer tags
       for (Element dealer : dealersList){     
           Elements dealerInfos = dealer.children();   // for each dealer tag select all child tags
           for(Element inf : dealerInfos){
               System.out.println(inf.tagName() +" : "+ inf.text());  //print tag name and if exists tag text
           }
           System.out.println("********************************");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Ran it on an async task and parsed the data into model objects. Thanks so much!